# Get the last part of the URI

Tags: php

if i output my URI i also get the folder in which it is located at.

```
echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //outputs /abcgetoutofjail/admin.php?make_account
```

im on localhost right now, and the website is under folder in htdocs `abcgetoutofjail`

**i need only `admin.php?make_account`**

i need the last part of the url in any way

how can i achieve that with either another way of getting uri or using a string function to cut SERVER URI

```
function DescriptionAndTitle($uri)
{
    echo $uri;

}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you're trying to accomplish. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: why the downvote? i ask how to cut string on a subject where it is related to the work uri, bringing help for others, plus i clearly said if there are other options please help. i dont see how my question is bad

Comment: @GrahamWalters im trying to get the last part of the uri, so if your site is at `sdfa.com/asdfa/asdf -->/asdf <----` i need that

Comment: ps I didn't downvote, but for next time, the downvotes are most probably because of the lack of effort shown.

Answer (score 1):

In Php, you can achieve this using [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) & [count](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) function.

```
$uri = '/some-dir/yourpage.php?q=bogus&n=10';

$uri = explode('/', $uri);
$len = count($uri);
print $uri[$len-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the last part of a URL I usually do something like the following:

```
 $url = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
 $partsofurl = explode("/", $url['path']); 
 $partyouwant = end($partsofurl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$needed_part = end(explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is what you're looking for:

```
$dir = explode('/', dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']));
$dir = '/'.end($dir);
echo $dir;
```

Comment: that only outputs the file, `abcgetoutofjail`

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the question. I've updated my code